# Comparing user-defined objects in two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `MyClass` where I have also overridden the `__eq__` method for comparing two objects of the class as I want to, and I can do this:

```
obj1 = MyClass(a = 2)
obj2 = MyClass(a = 2)

obj1 == obj2 # gives me True
```

Now my problem is that I have two lists including objects of this class, and I want to compare whether or not the `set` of these two lists are the same. Such that I expect that:

```
list1 = [MyClass(a=1), MyClass(a=2)]
list2 = [MyClass(a=2), MyClass(a=1)]

set(list1) == set(list2)
```

gives me `True`. But I run into this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'MyClass'
```

which is clearly because of the `set()` line. How can I do this? (I don't care about using or not using `set` as long as I can compare two lists of objects compared regardless of their order.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) concerning what makes a class hashable. You will need to implement both `__eq__` and `__hash__`. You will need to ensure that objects that are *equal* to one another also produce the same hash value.